# Plugin Before not working

Tags: magento2

I am trying to understand functionality of plugin method. for that i have created a custom module and i added below code in di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Model\StudyPlugin">
        <plugin name="studyPluginBefore" type="Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Plugin\Model\StudyPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and model class code is

```
namespace Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Model;
class StudyPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function getName($name){
            return $name;
    }
}
```

after that my plugin method code is

```
namespace Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Plugin\Model;
class StudyPlugin
{

    public function beforeGetName(\Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Model\StudyPlugin $subject, $name){
        die('hello');
        return ['(' . 'My name is '.$name . ')'];
    }

}
```

and at last i have created a block class and below is the code of that block class.

```
namespace Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Block\StudyPlugin;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class PluginBlock extends Template 
{

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Adhikari\StudyPlugin\Model\StudyPlugin $studyPlugin,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_studyPlugin = $studyPlugin;

    }

    public function getName($name){
        return $this->_studyPlugin->getName($name);
    }
}
```

but when i include that block in homepage and call block function getName('hello'); it doesn't code in before plugin method. but i calls model class method getName($name) and return value.

can someone please help me to understand the workflow of this or if i am doing some mistake..

Comment: What is the error ?
Is it a blank page or you have a message ?
First, remove the `die('hello');` in your plugin method.

Comment: I used die to check whether plugin is being called or not.. and there is no error.. it just return  hello. But if I am using before method it should return die.. @Vinz

Comment: Basic question but did you run the command `./bin/magento  setup:di:compile` ?

Comment: Yes of course I did.. that's why block method is being called and it's returning value from model class